# How can I lessen using the RAM when I use image with PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am working on a project and it has a lot of pictures in it to describe the choices

[image]

and this project Should work on weak computers when I see how much of that program using of RAM I see it is using a lot of resources from RAM because there are a lot of pictures in it.

[image]

it is using 319MB of RAM

How can I lessen using the RAM when I use pictures?

or how can solve this problem?

I tried to change the extensions of images from png to jpeg and I tried many extensions but I failed

and when I deleted the pictures it was using 90MB of RAM

Comment: Is resizing the image an option for you or do you need to keep the original size?

Comment: if you mean resizing the image to be smaller no that is not an option i need to keep it in the same size but if you mean making the quality of image less that what it is know yes that is an option for me

Comment: The pixel size might be relevant: if you're scaling the images (for instance, the source is 1000x1000 but you're showing it in a widget that is 100x100), then they will still occupy a lot of memory; if this is your case, then you should generate the images at the correct size; if it's not, then you could consider doing the opposite: generate images at a smaller size and then display it scaled to the size you need. The image compression, instead, is almost irrelevant, as Qt keeps an internal cache of images as uncompressed pixel data, so it doesn't matter if the source was a JPG or a BMP.

Comment: Note that, seeing the screenshot, you should consider using svg images instead of raster ones, and show them with [QSvgWidget](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgwidget.html). I've never tested it, but it *should* be better in terms of memory, since the images are vectorial.